# How would I make a Firebase query to select information between unique ID's?

Tags: javascript, json, database, select, firebase

I am trying to select all information from a child between the specified children using startAt and endAt but I keep getting null returned instead of the values. I have the children's unique ID's set through the set method in another function, so they are not randomly generated by firebase. The code I am using to select is below as well as my firebase data structure. What am I doing wrong?

Select code to view data between 2015-10-15 and 2015-10-17:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#view").click(function(){
  var startDate = document.getElementById("datePickerStart").value;
  var endDate = document.getElementById("datePickerEnd").value;
    ref.child("logs").startAt(startDate).endAt(endDate).once("value", function(dataSnapshot) {
      console.log(dataSnapshot.val());
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
    });
});
```

Data structure:

```
logs/
  2015-10-15
    message: my message 1
  2015-10-16
    message: my message 2
  2015-10-17
    message: my message 3
```

Comment: Try `ref.child("logs").orderByKey().startAt(startDate).endAt(endDate)`